# Extracting Ridges from DEM ALOS

Tags: dem, extract

I'm currently working on a forestry project for my thesis. It consists of the optimization of skids tracks planification using ALOS images.  To this end
I would like to extract obstacles such as steep slopes, stream and ridges as they are key zones for the skidding.

This question will focus on the extraction of ridges line.

I tried the inversion of the DEM and the hydrology analysis (Catchment Area then Channel Network using less-than 200 threshold methods) but the results aren't satisfying enough.

Do you know any way to extract ridges using QGIS and DEM?

Comment: You seem to be seeking a review of your work instead of asking a focused question.

Comment: You could try [r.param.scale](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/r.param.scale.html) which "extracts terrain parameters from a digital elevation model", including ridges

Comment: @BERA, thank you, it is giving interesting result, but i'm seeking line instead of areas.
Still, I think it'll be usefull, thank you very much